# Cannot find any react class

Tags: android, react-native

I created a react-native project and opened it in android studio, but got these errors

```
package com.project1;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;     //cannot find
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;      //cannot find
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;         //cannot find
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;   //cannot find
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;             //cannot find

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

 private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
@Override
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
  return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage()
  );
}

@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
  return "index";
}
};

@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
return mReactNativeHost;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}
}
```

Here all the react classes throw error android studio simply couldn't find anything.

I also read all the posts from stackoverflow and github but nothing seems to work nothing really.
I am frustrated now because after 4 days i got this project running after getting through all sorts of trouble with 0.56.0 in windows. I had to switch to ubuntu and had to use 0.55.4 and then i got this project up for running but now i am getting these errors.

Also this is my project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"

    }
    google()

}
}
```

And here is app level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
//buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4'

}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}
```

This is the screenshot from android studio
[image]

Comment: why are you trying to open it in android studio ?

Comment: had to add few dependencies

Comment: related to some sdk i am importing

Comment: you can also do the same thing by editing the gradle file manually from any editor

Comment: @JayThummar ok i admit i can do it outside,  but the question is different please suggest me why is android studio throwing error. Or the android studio always throws this error??

Comment: @JayThummar I don't know how to do this outside android studio and even if it is possible,  my question is why is android studio throwing all these errors

Comment: i think this is because React and react native are installed inside node module and we are opening only android module thats why these errors are occured

Comment: @JayThummar Can you describe in detail like what changes do i need to make to make this work

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of your android studio

Comment: @ChiragSharma added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

First of all as you were getting at react-native@0.56.0 problem , Yes that's a bug in react-native library as it is incompatible with some other dependencies. I have answered this question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463370/bundling-failed-error-plugin-0-provided-an-invalid-property-of-default/51760632#51760632)

Now if you are getting the error that android studio was not able to found react libraries then it happens for two reasons that i know.

1. You are opening android project by copy/paste the **project1/android** found somewhere else and then opening from android studio.
2. You are not connected with the internet since it loads something from internet before building.

Second thing if you are opening your react project in android studio you can only build it from there still you need **Metro Bundler** running to run your app. To run it use **react-native start** command in cmd inside your react-native project.

I was able to successfully open my react-native project in android studio and building there but able to run is if **Metro Bundler** has running and provided the screenshot of it.

After checking above two things you still get error try

1. Deleting **node_modules** from project
2. Then run **npm install --save**
3. Then run **react-native run-android** to check whether the application run in emulator or not.

Try above things and let me know if you still gets error.

[image: Android Studio ScreenShot]

[image: Visual Studio Code Screenshot]

Gradle (Module:app) :-

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.profileui"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Gradle (Project : project_name)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

Comment: I haven't done any of the 2 points you mentioned. I opened android studio project from that specific folder only and yes internet is connected.

Comment: I already tried your solution that deleting node_modules several times. I already mentioned i tried most of the things from stack overflow. I googled this thing and got several threads but nothing seems to work in my case.
I don't know why the hell this framework is so buggy it wont even let me run a simple hello world... BTW if you have any other suggestion do comment

Comment: Is your application running by react-native run-android ?. If Yes then the problem is with android studio i guess. I am providing screenshots of my Gradle configuration.Check it and also update android studio if update available.

Comment: You have added many android related dependecies in Gradle . I don's think they are required take a look.