# React-Native brand new project issues

Tags: react-native

While creating new react-native project using the cli `react-native init` the project gets created successfully but when running it with cli react-native `run-android` it started giving following error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C1kh.png)

Here is the package.json file for the newly created project.

```
{
  "name": "TempApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

after a long hurdle, I just replaced a package.json file from one of my old project to the new one then the new project is started running with the cli.

here is my new package.json

```
{
  "name": "TempApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.13.1",
    "react-native-shared-preferences": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

if you compare these json file, you can say that the project is running with slightly older version of react-native.

My question here is, is there any stable version recommendation from react-native ?

Comment: Yes ,There is discussion going there with the incompatible versions on github. For now you can see this for your answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463370/bundling-failed-error-plugin-0-provided-an-invalid-property-of-default/51760632#51760632

Comment: If you are using Windows, then you have to wait for React 0.57